# PHP filters for imagick without using exec

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

How can I filter an image with imagick without using exec?

I'd want to obtain a grayscale and a duotone filter.

Comment: Nothing because I don't find any PHP Imagick function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an PECL extension for it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: I know this extension but I don't know how to get a grayscale image with it.

Comment: I think setImagetype is your friend: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagetype.php

The available types you find here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagetype.php

Comment: Ok setImageType (or modulateImage) solves a half of the problem. I still need a duotone filter.

Comment: Google showed me this result for how to do a duotone filtering of an image with imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#duotone

And it seems you can use all the operations described also with this PHP extension, for example the tint: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.tintimage.php

I must admit the documentation of the tint method wouldn't have brought me far :-)

Comment: That is the same, the PECL extension is just a wrapper for the Imagemagick library: "Imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API."

Comment: How would you write it with imagick functions? With the php documentation I don't have a clue.

Comment: Basic usage examples are here:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php

It is quite easy, you open your image file:

$im = new Imagick("test.png");

Do something with it (all the methods in the docs can be called on this object:

/* Create a border for the image */
$im->borderImage(new ImagickPixel("white"), 5, 5);

And give it out:

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $im;

Or write it in a file:

$im->writeImage('test2.png');